# What is the name of the practice of mapping problems and their inter connected relationships?

Tags: communication, methodology, documentation, definition, terminology

Some time ago I saw an article about a model where the different problems or dysfunctions of a team (or company) where identified.

Then, once the problems are identified, the relationship between them were defined using from > to arrows. The process was fairly simple and yet very easy for different audiences to understand the relationship between problems, identifying the key areas to focus efforts as they could enable other areas for improvement.

Below is an example of how it'd more or less look like. Problems and dependencies mentioned are merely illustrative.
[image: Problem Dependency workflow]

ps.: I'm not referring to Root Cause Analysis (RCA) as it's mostly based on 5 whys or Ishikawa /
fishbone diagrams, although I understand it may be a slightly different approach for RCA.

Comment: At first I didn't see this question as a PM question, but the more I thought about it--and about Thomas' answer--the more I'm glad you brought this up. Structural dysfunction absolutely should be on topic here, at least as it relates to PM, so maybe we need tags for RCA and other process/organizational terms so people can see how and when they're on topic. If I get a few upvotes on the comment, I'll move this to meta for further discussion. :)

Comment: You have my upvote, @ToddA.Jacobs!

Comment: Done. See https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/921/4271 for the discussion. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be either a [causal map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_map) or a [causal loop diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_loop_diagram).

If it is a causal map, then the direction of the arrow indicates the influence. For example, "lack of priorities" causes "different KPIs" and "silos" cause "lack of communication".

The causal loop diagram is more comprehensive and would also be explicit about the relationship as well as showing any reinforcement loops. These elements aren't currently present on the diagram, though.

Comment: The causal map is exactly what I was looking for, thanks Thomas! I really liked the causal loop diagram as it's better structured to represent systemic relationships... I'll expand the one I'm building!